# ValueError: Shapes (None, 22) and (None, 10) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been working on this excercise but I'm getting this error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

The error log is the following:
ValueError: Shapes (None, 22) and (None, 10) are incompatible

here is the code:

```
#Loading required packages
import time
import sympy
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import collections
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get Data and store in dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('/home/Table.csv',dtype=np.float32 )
df = df.dropna()
df.drop('id', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.head()

re_df = df.to_numpy().reshape(3,1066,22)

X = re_df[:, 3]
y = re_df[:,-1] 

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    # Add the Flatten Layer
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    # Build the input and the hidden layers
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(40, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    # Build the output layer
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

# Compile the model

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])


--> history = model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=5, validation_split=0.3) # Start training process
```

In this last line is when the error seems to occur, stating that Shapes (None, 22) and (None, 10) are incompatible.

How can I fix this?
thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the error with dummy data [here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/91abc33e813b22c4c923c8b22d872230/untitled94.ipynb). From the input it seems like the number of classes is 22.

Hence, replacing the following line of code

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
```

with the code below will help

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(22, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
```